# Initializing std::map with MFC objects doesn't compile

Tags: c++, mfc

MFC beginner here.

I've tried to initialize `std::map` like this: (in the header of CView)

```
// myprogramView.h
std::map<int, CStatic> myMap = {{10,{}}, {11,{}}};
```

But the compiler complains *"no instance of constructor ... matches the argument list".*

<sub>(Edit for future reference) The above message was an error from IntelliSense. The compiler(MSVC) says: C2664 'std::map<int,CStatic,std::less,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>::map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>'</sub>

However, we can do these kinds of initializations:

```
std::map<int, std::string> myMap2 = { {10,{}}, {11,{}} };
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>> myMap3 = { {10,{}}, {11,{}} };
```

Why doesn't the first example compile, and how can I use a map containing MFC objects?

I'm trying to access the control object in the map and `.Create()` it during the run-time or in the `OnCreate`.

I also tried `CMap` but it seems the same problem occurs.

---

Question resolved by j6t's answer. Just want to clarify that the answer is talking about `std::initializer_list`, **not** 'member initializer list'.

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Comment: Seems unusual to want to initialize a `std::map` with values that aren't ultimately going to be used. What's the *real* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @IInspectable I just wanted to make some labels for texts, in a for loop. So I thought creating a map containing `CStatic`s would be convenient, since I can access them by key. (the key will be different in the for loop). Maybe I could use std::vector, etc., this was just a quick idea.

Comment: Why don't you just store a map of control IDs and their respective text entries? Or really, if this is all known at compile time, why not simply an array of structs that contain the ID and text? [`CWnd::GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgitem) turns a control ID into a control. Or simply call [`CWnd::SetDlgItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#setdlgitemtext).

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, thanks for the suggestion. I should really think about better engineering (right now I'm just trying to quickly implement and refactor later). Anyway, my project is an SDI. Could you give me any hint of what I should use for SDI project instead of GetDlgItem or SetDlgItemText?

Comment: The window classes in an SDI project derive from `CWnd`, so you can just use those members as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MFC objects that derive from `CObject` (like `CStatic`) cannot be copied; they have a deleted copy constructor. But initialization from an initializer list requires objects that are copy-constructible.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason MFC objects are designed to be non-copyable?

Comment: Yes: [Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/serialization-in-mfc) support.

Comment: Yes. GUI elements have "identity" and must not be copied.

Comment: No, that's not the reason. Clearly, a [`CArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class) isn't a GUI element (but derives from `CObject`, so it isn't copyable either).

Comment: But the decision to derive `CArray` from `CObject` is just a historic accident from the days back when C++ was still in its infancy. If the designers in those days back had had and known the tools and techniques that we use today (including serialization), they would have made different decisions.

Comment: They would not have. Every serializable object in MFC needs to derive from `CObject`, as that provides the all the low-level support (such as instantiating objects by class name). Unlike MFC's exception handling, serialization support is neither a historic accident nor from the days when C++ was in its infancy.

Comment: @IInspectable Why does serialization in MFC need the objects (that are going to be serialized) to be non-copyable? Indeed, as you know, `std::vector` or `std::map` containing copyable objects such as `std::string` can be serialized.

Comment: @starriet Serialization support requires that you derive from `CObject`. `CObject` has a private copy-c'tor to prevent accidental pass-by-value. Obviously, one can devise a serialization strategy for *any* data type. But if you want to use the built-in serialization of MFC, you'll have to derive from `CObject` and inherit its property of not being copyable.

Comment: I know mentioning just an appreciation in SO comments are not recommended, but anyway greatly appreciate the answer and discussions by j6t and @IInspectable. Thanks again.